# PCB design for Renesas' DA7212 audio codec

Tags: pcb, routing, via, manufacturing, audio-codec

I'm designing my very first PCB. I managed to route all my components and I'm stuck at the last footprint - DA7212 from Renesas:

[image: DA7212 package info]

Those balls are both incredibly tiny and packed dense. I'd need a manufacturer with a minim clearance <1 mil to route between the balls, or a via of ~0.4 mm. Which sounds doable, until one considers the minimum annular width of most PCB manufacturers I know of (that doesn't cost an arm and a leg).

Any tips as to how I could route this infernal hardware?

Some clarifications: this is the lowest power codec I know of (and I've tried a couple). I don't have a viable replacement. This family of codecs comes only in WLCSP packages.

I can't use PDM or I2S microphones directly, I absolutely need to go with electret mics.

Comment: Via-in-pad may be your only option.

Comment: Have you looked for a third party breakout board?

Comment: I have strict space constraints. The breakout boards I've found are well beyond my space budget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have good experience with both jlcpcb and pcbway on such sized BGAs. You will have to use vias in pad (plugged and plated over). Do not route between the pads as that will add extreme  manufacturing requirements as you said youself.  Make sure that pads with vias and those without have the same size (a via can essentially expand the pad due to minimum annular ring size, which can lead to inconsistent soldering). This kind of process costs you at least about a $100 per run (as of 2023).